# cygwin sshd service not starting

Tags: cygwin, sshd

I used service account to install cygwin and sshd service. It was working fine till service account password was changed. Now, sshd service is not coming up.

```
$ net start sshd
System error 1069 has occurred.

The service did not start due to a logon failure.
```

Can somebody help and share the steps to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Likely a reset of needed privileges.
For that I use the following script:

```
$ cat bin/enable-cyg-server.sh
#!/bin/bash

#  see
# /usr/share/csih/cygwin-service-installation-helper.sh
#
editrights -u cyg_server -a SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege
editrights -u cyg_server -a SeCreateTokenPrivilege
editrights -u cyg_server -a SeTcbPrivilege
editrights -u cyg_server -a SeServiceLogonRight
editrights -u cyg_server -a SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege

editrights -u sshd -a SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege
editrights -u sshd -a SeCreateTokenPrivilege
editrights -u sshd -a SeTcbPrivilege
editrights -u sshd -a SeServiceLogonRight
editrights -u sshd -a SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege
```

Comment: I ran above commands, but still it is throwing same error. @matzeri